# 64k NTFS allocation size performance benefit for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently setting up SQL Server 2014 and just wanted to know if SQL will benefit from allocating 64k to the NTFS partition?
Sorry I didn't state, my current workload will be for both OLTP and OLAP processes.

Thanks,

Shola

Answer (score 0, accepted):

64K sectors work well with SQL Server storage in most situations, but benchmark your particular circumstances (which you do not state) to be certain.